# Determine if Poisson process rate changes

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, poisson-distribution, stochastic-processes

Imagine a person, P, calls into a call center multiple times an hour. With 50% probability, P will call with some low rate (like an average of ~3 calls an hour) the whole time. With 50% probability, P will start the hour calling with a larger rate (like ~30 calls an hour); however, at any time during the hour P has some probability to stop calling so much, and settle into the slower rate (of ~3 calls per hour).

If we look at the probability distribution for how many calls will be received over the hour, it will be close to a sum of Poisson distributions, looking like a bimodal distribution:[image]

Notably, there is a low probability "bridge" between the two peaks (most visible between 10 and 20 calls), which are cases where P stopped calling so much at some point during the hour. Concretely, one such hour of calls may look like the following:
[image]
where we see in the first half hour P was calling at a high rate, but then switched to a low rate about half an hour in. To be very clear, in reality the only data we have access to is the blue curve (cumulative number of calls), NOT the orange curve (which is essentially what we are trying to infer, but which I've included here just for illustration purposes).

The problem is, given such a timeline of when calls were received during the hour (as shown above), can we decide with very high probability:

1. Did P start off calling at the higher rate?
2. If (1) is true, at some point did P start calling at the lower rate?

Essentially, our goal is to infer the orange "True or False" curve in the above plot from the blue "Cumulative number of calls vs time" curve. I don't really care when the change from True to False happens, only determining if it did happen.

For (1), we can maybe set some threshold in the total number of calls, and for instance say if more than 10 calls were received, then P must've been calling in at a high rate at the start.

For (2) it is a bit trickier. One thought is that the call log will likely show many more calls during early minutes of the hour than later minutes of the hour. For instance, I've thought to look at the distribution of delays between calls, rather than the total number of calls, but haven't found a super fruitful way to formulate the decision in this case. Still, I feel like the fact we have the entire call log should shed more light on answering this question than just setting a threshold in total number of calls could.

Any help or pointers for how to think about this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You seem to be looking for a change-point model.

Comment: That seems to be highly relevant! Do you have any suggestions for pertinent resources to my use case above?

Comment: A change point model would make sense if you had presented time series data suggesting some points in time where the statistical properties change. What I would suggest given the histogram you've presented is a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution).

Comment: I've added a bit more information to the OP: I think a change point model probably is what I am interested in (I hadn't head that term before), because I have access to time series data of the cumulative number of calls vs time, and want to determine if at any point the call rate changes from the "high" rate to the "low" rate - as I'm not too familiar with the literature, any suggestions for relevant resources to this specific case?

Comment: Okay, cool. In which case you readily put an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) into your Poisson model to select for the $\lambda$ before or after the change point, respectively.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - I would've thought that I would essentially need to do a hypothesis test of some sort as to whether a change point existed. All I have access to is a given log of the cumulative number of calls over an hour - I don't actually have access to whether P is calling at a high rate or not (which I guess would be your indicator function).

Comment: I see. I personally don't have any interest in null hypothesis significance tests, so I may not be the person to answer. Life's been good without them and I don't want them back  But seriously, what you could do is fit the change-point version of the Poisson model and do an orthogonal contrast as your test statistic.

Comment: I am halfway your post and I have to make the comment that I am struggling with the example. What real world situation has a person call into a call center so many times?

Comment: Is there more knowledge about the probability how often the two states change? Or do you consider some sort of restrictions on the number of switch points? I believe that assumptions about this are neccesary. Otherwise one could consider each single event seperately and consider the waiting times (which are exponential distributed) and for each period between events assign a seperate independent estimate depending in the tine between the events. Or one could also consider situations where the state switches several times between two calls.

Comment: You know there is only one possible switch time. I'm not sure of the probability, but something like ~10% chance that at some point over the entire call the switch happens. 

The example is just to get something illustrative for the math, I don't think such a call center is that realistic :)

Comment: There are different approaches. You can try to maximize a likelihood. But if you also have more clear information about the probabilities of switch points then you can apply a Bayesian approach which combines the likelihood with a prior. An alternative to the latter is to use some penalty for the amount of switch points and optimise this with cross validation. ...

Comment: ... with so many options it would be nice to have a more focused, narrowly defined question.

Comment: Hm, I guess the core of the question is just, for a Poisson process that changes rate at most once over some time period, where the probability of the change occurring at all sometime during the time period is ~10%, how to best detect if the change in rate did indeed occur from just measurements of the overall process